# Mockito "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type" on getter

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I'm trying to generate a mock for a class witch contains a getter, the source code of the class is:

```
class AppContext {
...
  AppLocalizations get l10n => AppLocalizations.of(navigatorMaterialAppKey.currentContext!);
}
```

Then I generate a mock of the class with mockito and with the following code:

```
@GenerateNiceMocks([
  MockSpec<AppContext>(),
])
```

When I run the tests I have the following error: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'AppLocalizations'`, it look like in the generated code, the mock code of the getter is not generated.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: getter is returning null and AppLocalizations set as return type, you need to make it 
nullable, AppLocalizations? get l10n => AppLocalizations.of(navigatorMaterialAppKey.currentContext!);

Comment: I don't want to make my getter nullable, normally with @GenerateNiceMocks it should generate a working code for the mock

Comment: `@GenerateNiceMocks` generate stubs for getters for me.  Did `flutter run build_runner build` report any errors or warnings?  Are you sure that the `.mocks.dart` file got regenerated?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've also tried to delete the `.dart_tool` folder and the `.mocks.dart` and generate again and it's the same, the getters are not generated

Comment: May be it comes from the packages version I'm using, I'm using mockito `5.3.2`and build_runner `2.3.0`

Comment: I'm using mockito 5.3.2 and build_runner 2.3.3 (but I doubt that the minor difference in build_runner versions matters).  Can you try to create a minimal, reproducible example and post the generated `.mock.dart` file?